# Unbiased estimator for UNIF($-\theta, \theta$)

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

I am searching for an unbiased estimator for $\theta$ in a UNIF($-\theta, \theta$) distribution, which looks like $\hat\theta = c(X_{n:n} - X_{1:n}$). The question is to search for the c that makes this estimator unbiased. I already found that $c = \cfrac{\theta}{E(X_{n:n} - X_{1:n})}$, because then $E(\hat\theta) = \theta$. By trial and error, I found that $E(X_{n:n} - X_{1:n}) = \cfrac{n+1}{n-1}*2\theta$ just by trying it for different values for n. But has anyone an idea how to proof this? I indeed get the right answer, but I don't now how to formally proof that $E(X_{n:n} - X_{1:n}) = \cfrac{n+1}{n-1}*2\theta$

Comment: this page helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: @Math-fun So I have to use the formula and fill it in for k = 1 and k = n to obtain $2\theta * (\frac{n}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1})$?

Comment: Even if you don't use any formula, the densities of  $X_{n:n}$ and $X_{1:n}$ are straightforward to derive from which you can find the required expectations. And if you know or you are allowed to use the (well-known) distributions of the order statistics, the work is even less.

Comment: @WillemAarts I would say so :-) have fun with it.